# Function of particles の and は in this sentence

Tags: particle-は, particle-の, nominalization

A girls tells this to her friend:

> このまま帰ってまた何日も会えなくなる**のは**嫌です

What are these particles doing here? は is being used to emphasize, to be the topic marker or the contrastive marker? My guess is that is the topic marker (?)
As for の, I don't really know. It doesn't seem like it's nominalizing.

Answer (score 5):

The の is nominalizing 会えなくなる and its preceding qualifying clause.

It might be easier to start from what comes after は.

> 嫌です

So the question becomes *what's* 嫌です? The は is going to indicate the answer for us.

> このまま帰ってまた何日も会えなくなるのは

Parsing this we can see that the first half or so of the sentence is giving context to 会えなくなるの (roughly, "not being able to meet again"). So we end up with something along the lines of "going home like this and not being able to meet again for many days"は嫌です. Without the の we don't have a noun to subjectify with は.

Comment: is correct to assume that: negative verb + naru = become unable of x? In the op case, become unable of meeting. I have trouble understanding the difference between 合えない and 合えなくなる

Comment: That's correct. In this case the kanji you want to use is 会 , though.